# Algebraic vs numerical equivalence of divisors over arbitrary fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

For a smooth projective variety over $k=\mathbb{C}$, it is known that algebraic and numerical equivalence coincide up to torsion. What about over arbitrary (alg. closed) fields $k$? I believe it may not be true but can't seem to find a reference that addresses this.

Comment: To get a counterexample you'll almost certainly need to add another formal hypothesis (i.e. a hypothesis beyond $k \ne \mathbb C$) such as $\operatorname{char}k = p > 0$ or $k \ne \bar k$ (or even $k \ne k^p$).